# How to interate data recived from db?

Tags: python, json, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting Data From DB but I want to return Few specific Columns to My Get API call.

I am Getting Multiple Dictionaries.

```
driver_data = MasterDriver.query.filter_by(Driver_Status_id=2, is_driver_verified=1)

 return drivers_schema.jsonify(driver_data)


[
    {

        "email_id": "abjhgfjhgc@xyz.com",
        "first_name": "manoj",
        "isActive": null,
        "last_name": "sayi",
        "license": null,
        "mobile_number": "+917780187505",

    },
{

        "email_id": "abjhgfjhgc@xyz.com",
        "first_name": "manoj",
        "isActive": null,
        "last_name": "sayi",
        "license": null,
        "mobile_number": "+917780187505",

    },
{

        "email_id": "abjhgfjhgc@xyz.com",
        "first_name": "manoj",
        "isActive": null,
        "last_name": "sayi",
        "license": null,
        "mobile_number": "+917780187505",

    }

]
```

Answer (score 1):

`null` is not existent in Python, you might be looking for `None`.

What you are trying to do is a very basic `for x in array` operation.

I suggest beginning with the basics of Python to be able to solve your problem.
Nevertheless, here's a working solution to retrieve the elements in your array

```
arr = [
    {

        "email_id": "abjhgfjhgc@xyz.com",
        "first_name": "manoj",
        "isActive": None,
        "last_name": "sayi",
        "license": None,
        "mobile_number": "+917780187505",

    },
{

        "email_id": "abjhgfjhgc@xyz.com",
        "first_name": "manoj",
        "isActive": None,
        "last_name": "sayi",
        "license": None,
        "mobile_number": "+917780187505",

    },
{

        "email_id": "abjhgfjhgc@xyz.com",
        "first_name": "manoj",
        "isActive": None,
        "last_name": "sayi",
        "license": None,
        "mobile_number": "+917780187505",

    }

]

for elem in arr:
    print(elem["email_id"])
    print(elem["first_name"])
    print(elem["isActive"])
    print(elem["last_name"])
    print(elem["license"])
    print(elem["mobile_number"])
```

You can have a look at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FlimsyModernAutosketch) to execute it.